# Can you redirect a user to a specific version in Tomcats parallel deployment

Tags: tomcat, deployment

When using Tomcats parallell deployment, Tomcat redirects users to different version according to this scheme:

- If no session information is present in the request, use the latest version.
- If session information is present in the request, check the session manager of each version for a matching session and if one is found, use that version.
- If session information is present in the request but no matching session can be found, use the latest version.

However, I would like to control myself which visitor gets to which version, so I can A/B test deployments.

Ideally, I should be able to control this through a valve, a cookie, header or similar. I've checked the code and documentation, but cannot find a way to externally control this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (Oct/2015) it is not possible.

There is a thread in Tomcat Users mailinglist where it is discussed:

> Parallel Deployment: Can I request a specific webapp version?